# Find an equation for a curve

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I go about trying to fit an equation to the data points shown in the chart below.  The chart was generated in Excel.  Excel generates the solid line when the chart type selected is scattered with smooth line.  The dotted line is the best equation that Excel can fit using "Add Trendline".  The curve is a plot of umbelliferone fluorescence versus hydroxyl ion concentration.  The smooth curve that Excel generated is approximately correct based on literature data that shows the fluorescence of umbelliferone versus pH (I chose to plot versus hydroxyl ion concentration and the x axis is a logarithmic scale).

So how could I go about trying to generate an approximate equation for the solid curve shown that would give a better fit than the logarithmic equation that Excel can come up with.

[image]

Comment: Do you only have four data points? It’s quite risky to infer any particular interpolation from so little data, unless you have expert knowledge on the subject that tells you what family of curves it should follow. That said, I think excel uses a *spline* fit to make the curve. These look good to the eye, but are generally not a good model for the data. I might guess the real relation is a sigmoid function, probably logistic growth (it would make sense to me given the title of the plot). But I’m definitely not an expert on the subject, so take that with a big grain of salt!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there many many possible equations you can create with 4 random points (polynomials, roots, hyperbolic etc.)

Here, I am just using a simple **polynomial equation**:

For the highest power polynomial, $x^{n}$, you need at least ${n+1}$ points (simplifies you life),

$\therefore$ It is possible for you to create a **full** equation, containing the highest power of **3** with your **4** points. $$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$$

Now use the points, create 4 simultaneous equations and solve for each of constants $(a, b, c, d)$ individually to get your equation. Like I said, it is possible to create other functions like roots or hyperbolics, or even possible to use higher polynomials but you are going to have constants as variables left behind.